# How to make invisible the unchecked check boxes in Custom adapter of my android application

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-adapter, custom-adapter, android-adapterview

I am developing an application in which i have an adapter which will display the check box on all user list as to select the particular person. After selecting a particular user or person all other check boxes need to invisible other than the selected user below is my adapter class

```
public class SuggestionReplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<SuggestionForumReplayModel> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context _context;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    private static CheckBox mSelectedRB;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public SuggestionReplayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SuggestionForumReplayModel> listData){
        this.listData = listData;
        _context = context;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder) 
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ViewHolder  holder;
         boolean isChecked;
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestionfromcustomercustomerview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.userImageiv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postOwnerImage);
            holder.userNametv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            holder.replyAnswer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postd_text);
            holder.timeEgotv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posted_date_and_time);
            holder.selectUserRadiobutton =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.winner_of_suggestion);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final SuggestionForumReplayModel suggestionItem = (SuggestionForumReplayModel) listData.get(position);

        holder.userNametv.setText(suggestionItem.getSuggestion_firstname());
        holder.replyAnswer.setText(suggestionItem.getSuggestion_forum_reply_content());
        holder.timeEgotv.setText(suggestionItem.getSuggestion_created_date());


        holder.selectUserRadiobutton.setOnClickListener(new CheckBox.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null){
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (CheckBox) view;

                AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
                alert.setTitle("Selcting User For Goodies");
                alert.setMessage("Please Confirm The Selected User ");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mSelectedRB.setChecked(true);
                        mSelectedPosition = position;
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
                            mSelectedRB.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        mSelectedPosition=position;
                        mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });

        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
            holder.selectUserRadiobutton.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            holder.selectUserRadiobutton.setChecked(true);
            mSelectedRB = holder.selectUserRadiobutton;
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(suggestionItem.getSuggestion_profile_photo(), holder.userImageiv, options,
            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                    FailReason failReason) {
                }

                @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                }
            }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                    int total) {
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        CheckBox selectUserRadiobutton;
        ImageView userImageiv;
        TextView userNametv;
        TextView replyAnswer;
        TextView timeEgotv;
    }
}
```

please help me to solve my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easy way is to have a method which will run through all the checkbox's present on your adapter and make'em invisible, like this pseudo/example code:

```
private void clearUnselectedCheckboxes() {

  for (Checkbox checkbox : adapter.getCheckboxList()) {
    if(checkbox.isChecked()){
      checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
  }
}
```

Where the **adapter.getCheckboxList()** is obviously the list of your present checkboxes.

Comment: where do i need to use it because i want to clear them in the custom adapter which i posted  my code. the code u suggested  gives error in the line  adapter.getCheckboxList() if i use it in the activity. please tell me how to do it in the adapter class i posted

Comment: Of course it gives an error, read the comment after the code, you'll have to put it on whatever context is needed, in your case on your stateChangedListener() of the checkboxes.